# gdm's systemd user process triggers automount

Tags: linux, systemd, gnome, automounting, gdm

I'm trying to set up a hard drive that's in an external enclosure, so I added the following fstab entry:

```
LABEL=Mothership /var/local/Mothership btrfs noauto,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=2,x-systemd.device-timeout=2 0 0
```

But everytime I try to boot, I get very strange automount requests, which when the drive is disconnected, outright block GDM as well as my ability to log in to any user account.

```
Got automount request for /var/local/Mothership, triggered by 641 (accounts-daemon)
Got automount request for /var/local/Mothership, triggered by 770 (systemd)
Got automount request for /var/local/Mothership, triggered by 770 (systemd)
Got automount request for /var/local/Mothership, triggered by 770 (systemd)
```

As it turns out, the `systemd` process at PID 770 is from `gdm`'s system user...

For context, the drive is used as an external Flatpak installation under `/etc/flatpak/installations.d`, as well as the target for certain symbolic links within `~/.var/app`

Comment: Also, I have another automount at filesystem root and that one isn't being spuriously triggered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it was precisely the combination of `x-systemd.automount` and it being configured as a flatpak installation. systemd's automount approach creates a virtual mountpoint that listens for access requests and triggers the actual mount, which throws the user process for `systemd` for a loop, as it looks for units in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`, of which flatpak installs are one.

I switched away from systemd automount and the deadlock is gone.